# "The selected disc image file isn't valid" error

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-7, burning, livedvd

I have been attempting to run Raring Ringtail (13.04) on my Windows 7 computer, just to see how it is. I'm not going to replace my whole OS... (yet.) Anyway, my BIOS doesn't support boot from USB so I am attempting to burn to DVD. I have it downloaded and used the Windows Disc Image Burner to attempt to burn it to my DVD. When I try to burn it, it gives me this error:

> The selected disc image file isn't valid.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/en/home) to burn the ISO? Always worked for me when burning ISO in Windows. Brasero just works now. :)

Check that your disc download matches the hashsum from Canonical for the download as well. Your download may have been corrupted or dropped packets in-flight. You would not want to start from a bad image.

Hope this helps.